# Bootstrap Navbar Menu Not Working Well After Hamburger Button Clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, navbar

Here's the normal size and view of the menu
[image: Here's the normal size and view of the menu]

And this is the view after reducing the size
[image: This is the view after reducing the size]

I mean in the second view the dropdowns should be listed downhills. But in the small navbar, it only adds the hamburger button. The others remains the same.

(I cencored the corporative names. The shapes don't mean anything.)

Here are the codes i use for layout.

Layout.cshtml

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="~/Content/logo.png" alt="Ana Sayfa" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Yönetim</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dosya Yükleme/Güncelleme</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cost Margin Yükleme", "Index", "CostMarginUpload")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("EK5 Tarife Yükleme", "Index", "EK5TariffUpload")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ETS Sourcing Cost Yükleme", "Index", "ETSSourcingUpload")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("ETS Sourcing Cost Tablosu Güncelleme", "Index", "ETSSourcingCost")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kullanıcı İşlemleri", "Index", "Users")</li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parametresi Güncelleme</a> 
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bölge Güncelleme", "Index", "Region")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bağlantı Tipi Güncelleme", "Index", "ConnectionTypes")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tarife Grubu Güncelleme", "Index", "TariffGroup")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profil Güncelleme", "Index", "Profile")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Parametreler Tablosu Güncelleme", "Index", "Parameters")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Zam Öngörüsü Girişi", "Index", "PriceIncreaseEstimates")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Müşteri İşlemleri", "Index", "Customers")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Fiyatlandırma İşlemleri</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Fiyatlandırma</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tekli Fiyatlandırma", "Index", "SinglePricing")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Çoklu Fiyatlandırma", "Index", "MultiPricing")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("İhale İçin Fiyatlandırma", "Index", "TenderPricing")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teklif Görüntüleme", "Index", "OfferView")</li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teklif Performans Bilgileri</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teklif Performans Bilgisi Görüntüleme", "Index", "PerformanceView")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teklif Performans Bilgisi Sıralama", "Index", "PerformanceRank")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li style="float:right">
                        @User.Identity.Name
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Scripts

```js
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo-js")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/kendo-css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


    <script src="Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu").kendoMenu();
            $(document.body).css("visibility", "visible");

            $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');f
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Styles

```css
html {
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #menu h2 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        #template img {
            float: left;
        }

        #template {
            width: 380px;
        }

        .nav > li {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }

        .navbar-inverse {
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }

        .navbar-nav {
            float: none;
        }
        .marginBottom-0 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -6px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
            display: block;
            content: " ";
            float: right;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
            border-left-color: #cccccc;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
            border-left-color: #555;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
            float: none;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        }
```

Comment: The same code works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/jIWAaIFzfOcuaA9xvh4P?p=preview. Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: Well, that's surprising. I do not get any error at console. But how can that be... I don't know.

Comment: The difference is the libs you include in <head>. Seems so... When i try to do the same, the @* syntax in been considered it as razor by the ide. How can i import them?
Thanks by the way.

Comment: I have updated the plunk now.

Comment: That didn't help again. There must be a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: you are using the library KendoMenu and it possibly adding class (and CSS) into your menu div.
In order to keep li into display block you can use the following code

```
.nav > li 
{ 
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

The `!important;` will lock this CSS property from  any future changes.

Comment: Thanks for consideration, but not even a navbar icon appears. After taking nav into the div you specifiy.

Comment: Just changed my answer

Comment: yes, the li element's display is set to inline. so what should it be? display: block or else?

Comment: It should be `.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}` which is from bootstrap css. Some of your CSS rules probably override Bootstrap rules.

Comment: I added my script and style stuff in the first post. I could not see any preventing issue.

Comment: Just edited my answer again, try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort to help. Well, not exactly the !important word solved, but your reminding that i use kendo menu helped a lot. I deleted the #menu.kendoMenu line of the JS. So that was the spy among the code who ruined all.  

Thank you mate, for your time. I appreciate.